# Firebase blocked by temporary_blocked2

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement database interation using Firebase Realtime database API. I managed to read data from db, but after some requests (or some time), I started to receive following error:

```
06-06 18:07:27.403 10820-12164/? I/AuthChimeraService: Executing request: ProxyRequest[ url: https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=AIzaSyCK4KTMJIMEwd8UhkA_Io467dt4KHgmAHU, method: 1 ]
06-06 18:07:27.421 1635-29264/? I/GCM.HTTP: Last HTTP status code for blocked entry: 500
06-06 18:07:27.421 1635-29264/? W/GCM.HTTP: HTTP request blocked due to automatic backoff: https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=AIzaSyCK4KTMJIMEwd8UhkA_Io467dt4KHgmAHU
06-06 18:07:27.422 10820-12145/? W/GoogleURLConnFactory: Blocked by temporary_blocked2: https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=AIzaSyCK4KTMJIMEwd8UhkA_Io467dt4KHgmAHU
06-06 18:07:27.424 10820-12164/? W/AuthChimeraService: ExecutionException for cause.
                                                   com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: ppb: Blocked by rule: temporary_blocked2
                                                       at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(SourceFile:151)
                                                       at jta.performRequest(SourceFile:64)
                                                       at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(SourceFile:113)
                                                    Caused by: ppb: Blocked by rule: temporary_blocked2
                                                       at pph.a(SourceFile:150)
                                                       at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.a(SourceFile:1784)
                                                       at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.execute(SourceFile:669)
                                                       at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.execute(SourceFile:653)
                                                       at com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack.performRequest(SourceFile:87)
                                                       at jsz.performRequest(SourceFile:66)
                                                       at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(SourceFile:96)
                                                       at jta.performRequest(SourceFile:64) 
                                                       at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(SourceFile:113)
```

User re-authorization helped, but after some time issue repeated. Anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Hello mol, could you give us a bit more info about the situation where you get this error? Is it possible that this starts happening around after an hour from signing in? If so, could you please try these [troubleshooting steps](https://drive.google.com/a/google.com/file/d/0B94LePkXiqa6SXVFd3N1NzJHX1E/view) and let us know if they helped?

Comment: Hello, Alfonso! Looks promising, I'll definitely try this out and give you a feedback, thank you!

Comment: Alfonso, that indeed helped, thanks a lot! You might post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Just did! Glad it helped